# Animation with firestore recycler view not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have found this library and I want to implement it in my app:
[cardslider-android--Github](https://github.com/Ramotion/cardslider-android/)

In my case I have events and I want to query their name, time, description and picture and, each time I select a card, they will change dynamically in the same fragment.

**This is the event adapter:**

```
    public class EventsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter < EventsModel, EventsAdapter.EventsViewHolder > {
    public EventsAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions < EventsModel > options) {
        super(options);
    }
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull EventsModel eventsModel) {
        holder.nameSwitcher.setText(eventsModel.getEvent_name());
        holder.timeSwitcher.setText(eventsModel.getEvent_date());
        holder.descriptionsSwitcher.setText(eventsModel.getEvent_desc());
        GlideApp.with(holder.eventpic.getContext())
            .load(eventsModel.getEvent_pic())
            .into(holder.eventpic);
        String documentID = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
        eventsModel.setDocid(documentID);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EventsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_past_event, parent, false);
        return new EventsViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class EventsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView eventname;
        private Button morebtn;
        private ImageView eventpic;
        private TextSwitcher nameSwitcher;
        private TextSwitcher timeSwitcher;
        private TextSwitcher descriptionsSwitcher;
        public EventsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameSwitcher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ts_name);
            timeSwitcher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ts_time);
            descriptionsSwitcher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ts_description);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Fragment:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root_past_event_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_past_event, container, false);

    mFirestoreList = (RecyclerView) root_past_event_view.findViewById(R.id.xrecyclerview_events);
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();



    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("events");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions < EventsModel > options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions
        .Builder < EventsModel > ()
        .setQuery(query, EventsModel.class)
        .build();
    adapter = new EventsAdapter(options);
    mFirestoreList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new CardSliderLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mFirestoreList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                onActiveCardChange();
            }
        }
    });
    mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new CardSliderLayoutManager(getContext()));

    new CardSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(mFirestoreList);
    mFirestoreList.setAdapter(adapter);

    nameSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) root_past_event_view.findViewById(R.id.ts_name);
    nameSwitcher.setFactory(new TextViewFactory(R.style.nameTextView, false));

    timeSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) root_past_event_view.findViewById(R.id.ts_time);
    timeSwitcher.setFactory(new TextViewFactory(R.style.timeTextView, false));

    descriptionsSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) root_past_event_view.findViewById(R.id.ts_description);
    descriptionsSwitcher.setInAnimation(getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
    descriptionsSwitcher.setOutAnimation(getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
    descriptionsSwitcher.setFactory(new TextViewFactory(R.style.DescriptionTextView, false));


    return root_past_event_view;
}

private void initRecyclerView() {



}

private void onActiveCardChange() {
    final int pos = layoutManger.getActiveCardPosition();
    if (pos == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || pos == currentPosition) {
        return;
    }

    onActiveCardChange(pos);
}


private void onActiveCardChange(int pos) {
    int animH[] = new int[] {
        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left
    };
    int animV[] = new int[] {
        R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom
    };

    final boolean left2right = pos < currentPosition;
    if (left2right) {
        animH[0] = R.anim.slide_in_left;
        animH[1] = R.anim.slide_out_right;

        animV[0] = R.anim.slide_in_bottom;
        animV[1] = R.anim.slide_out_top;
    }

    //setCountryText(countries[pos % countries.length], left2right);

    nameSwitcher.setInAnimation(getContext(), animV[0]);
    nameSwitcher.setOutAnimation(getContext(), animV[1]);

    timeSwitcher.setInAnimation(getContext(), animV[0]);
    timeSwitcher.setOutAnimation(getContext(), animV[1]);


    currentPosition = pos;
}

private class TextViewFactory implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    @StyleRes
    final int styleId;
    final boolean center;

    TextViewFactory(@StyleRes int styleId, boolean center) {
        this.styleId = styleId;
        this.center = center;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());

        if (center) {
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            textView.setTextAppearance(getContext(), styleId);
        } else {
            textView.setTextAppearance(styleId);
        }

        return textView;
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

I changed the LayoutInflater to include the whole fragment and I do not get a single card but the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you debug your code and try to saw why is it coming null?

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @jayeshjain yess

Comment: @AlexMamo 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.TextSwitcher.setText(TextSwitcher.java:78)
        at com.exemple.test.models.EventsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(EventsAdapter.java:31)
        at com.exemple.test.models.EventsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(EventsAdapter.java:22)`

Comment: We're not interested in the number of the line but the line itself, that produces that error.

Comment: @AlexMamo
`holder.nameSwitcher.setText(eventsModel.getEvent_name());
    holder.timeSwitcher.setText(eventsModel.getEvent_date());
    holder.descriptionsSwitcher.setText(eventsModel.getEvent_desc());` ; in the onBindViewHolder

Comment: So most likely "nameSwitcher", "timeSwitcher" or "descriptionsSwitcher" are null, right?

Comment: Check your layout `fragment_past_event` for any typos in the IDs, check if the ids are correct as `ts_time`, `ts_name` and `ts_description`. This is a NPE which, in your case, means any of the `TextView` you're setting the text to is null and not found.